# How do I remove the orange reflection on the bottle? (coming from ground) (cycles)

Tags: light, reflection

Can you please help me if there is a way to remove this lighter reflection on the bottle. I guess its coming from the ground. I have tried to increase roughness but it didn't worked.
I have no idea about light paths. Guess it can be the answer?
I'm pretty new in blender.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to **Object Properties** and scroll to the **Visibility** menu. Then inside of it, open the **Ray Visibility** menu. Inside that, uncheck "Glossy".